# C++ array assign error: invalid array assignment

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I'm not a C++ programmer, so I need some help with arrays.
I need to assign an array of chars to some structure, e.g.

```
struct myStructure {
  char message[4096];
};

string myStr = "hello"; // I need to create {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}

char hello[4096];
hello[4096] = 0;
memcpy(hello, myStr.c_str(), myStr.size());

myStructure mStr;
mStr.message = hello;
```

I get `error: invalid array assignment`

Why it doesn't work, if `mStr.message` and `hello` have the same data type?

Comment: You have to use strcpy or memcpy function instead of mstr.message = hello.

Comment: The line `hello[4096] = 0;` is wrong.  This is one past the last element of the array.  Just remove this line.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because you can't assign to arrays -- they're not modifiable l-values. Use strcpy:

```
#include <string>

struct myStructure
{
    char message[4096];
};

int main()
{
    std::string myStr = "hello"; // I need to create {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}
    myStructure mStr;
    strcpy(mStr.message, myStr.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

And you're also writing off the end of your array, as Kedar already pointed out.

Comment: Actually, the arrays `mStr.message` and `hello` in Alex's code **are** lvalues, because the expressions `&mStr.message` and `&hello` are valid. (See section 5.3.1 paragraph 3 in the C++ standard.)

Comment: Yup, you're right -- sorry. It seems what I should have said was that myStr.message isn't a *modifiable* l-value.

Comment: Interesting. What's the motivation for this? I don't see an issue with assignment to arrays constituting copying the memory over.

Comment: @Claudiu My assumption would be it has to do with the fact that the array variable name itself in C refers to the pointer of the start address of the array and the type of the arrray does in principle not contain information about it's length. So a direct assignment would be a pointer assignment which you rarely want and an automatic array copy is not possible because the length is unkown from the type. With memcpy you have to specify the length.

Answer (score 14):

> Why it doesn't work, if `mStr.message` and `hello` have the same data type?

Because the standard says so. Arrays cannot be assigned, only initialized.

Answer (score 4):

The declaration `char hello[4096];` assigns stack space for 4096 chars, indexed from `0` to `4095`. 
Hence, `hello[4096]` is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use memcpy to copy arrays.