# Initialize multidimensional array dynamically in c++

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

How can I initialize ptr dynamically with new:

```
int values1[4][2] = {{2,3},{-4,0},{3,-7},{2,2}};
int values2[4][2] = {{1,1},{-2,-3},{4,12},{-5,25}};
    
int (*ptr[2])[4][2] = {&values1,&values2};
```

I tried the following but I get a mistake:

```
int *ptr = new int[2*4*2]{&values1,&values2};
```

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason not to, you should use containers for this, and not c-style arrays: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Comment: I'm trying to use dynamic array...

Comment: Dynamic array: [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: I can't use vector either

Comment: Why? Are you learning C or C++?

Comment: I'm trying to use C concepts in C++

Comment: @Melissa *I'm trying to use C concepts in C++* -- The question is again, why?  Use C++.  C and C++ are two separate languages.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand this concept of initializing a 3d dynamic array with a 2d array.

Comment: Well, that's not a good idea. Choose a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typedef can help with this kind of tricky code

```
int values1[4][2] = { { 2, 3 }, { -4, 0 }, { 3, -7 }, { 2, 2 } };
int values2[4][2] = { { 1, 1 }, { -2, -3 }, { 4, 12 }, { -5, 25 } };

typedef int(*xxx)[2];

int main()
{
    xxx* ptr = new xxx[2];
    ptr[0] = values1;
    ptr[1] = values2;
    return 0;
}
```

I honestly have no idea how you would write it without the `xxx` typedef

**EDIT**

This appears to be the correct non-typedef version

```
int(**ptr)[2] = new (int(*[2])[2]);
```

I'm not quite sure I believe it.

Comment: Thank you, although I'm trying to use new

Comment: @Melissa See edit. I'm working on a non-typedef version.

Answer (score 0):

With all that said about containers, you can do this:

```
int (*ptr)[4][2];


ptr = new int[2][4][2]{{{2,3},{-4,0},{3,-7},{2,2}},{{1,1},{-2,-3},{4,12},{-5,25}}};
```

Comment: Thank you! Although, how can I call values1 and values2 instead of writing all the values into the {}? `ptr = new int[2][4][2]{&values1,&values2}` doesn't work

Comment: Also is this a dynamic array?

Comment: You can't write it like that, because the {} does magic here :)

Comment: oh ok, is there another way I could initialize with new without rewritting the values?

Comment: Dynamic in the sense that it's dynamically allocated. Not dynamic in the sense that it won't extend as you add new values.

Comment: Yeah no I won't add new values but I was just wondering if there was another way

Comment: You can have a look at this why this won't work in c++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118732/c-array-assign-error-invalid-array-assignment

Comment: You can of course create a copy function, like it is done for strings as strcpy...